# Quadratic equation problem. Composition of functions

Tags: quadratics

Suppose $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are quadratic polynomials and the three largest roots of $p(q(x))$ are $10$, $20$ and $23$. What is the smallest root of $p(q(x))$?

Then, there will be 4 roots. $q(10)$ $q(20)$ $q(23)$ $q$(another zero) will make the functions equal to zero. The rest...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Let the roots of $ p(x) = 0 $ be $\alpha, \beta$.

What can you say are the values of $ q(10), q(20), q(23) $?

> They are either $ \alpha$ or $\beta$. Note that at most two of them have the same value, since $q(x)$ is a quadratic function.

Hence, can you conclude what the possibilities of the last root is? (Note, there is more than 1 possibility)

> We split into casework, depending on what values they are.
>  Case 1: $q(10) = \alpha, q (20) = \beta , q (23) = \alpha $. The last solution is $r$ and satisfies $ q(r) = \beta$.
>  Observe that for any constant $C$, the solutions to $q(x) = C$ sum up to the same value by Vieta's formula. Hence, we have $ 10 + 23 = 20 + r$, which gives $r = 13$.

Complete the rest of the cases.

Comment: I don't understand. The values for those function are the zeroes for the composition.

Comment: @user11355 We know that $ p ( q (10) ) = 0 $ right? What does that tell us about $ q(10)$?

Comment: The y value is the root of p(x)

Comment: They are unversed functions? The y value turns into x value.

Comment: $q(10)= \alpha $ or $\beta$. Do you see why?

Comment: Yes, i see. Does that help

Comment: Then it's casework. If $q(10) = \alpha, q(20) = \beta, q(23) = \alpha$, what is the last root going to be?

Comment: Wait, how do you determine which two roots yield the same value .

Comment: As I said, casework. You have 3 cases to deal with.

Comment: In that case, q(n) is gonna be equal to $\beta$

Comment: Can we figure out the two functions, if they are equal to the same number?

Comment: No, the functions have an additional degree of freedom to them

Comment: Then how do we know what $n$ is?

Comment: Do you want be to plug in the values into the quadratic equation?

Comment: No. In the case that I have, the last root of $p(q(x))$ is 13. Do you see why?

Comment: Yes, I plugged in the values, solved the equation. Since 429a+13b=0...

Comment: Yes. Though, you can simplify it by considering the quadratic graph. 13=23+10-20. Alternatively, use the fact that the sum of roots to $p(x) =C$ is a constant, so 10+23=20+13

Comment: Shouldn't it be q(n) +q(10)=q(23)+q(20). If the sum of the two roots is constant.

Comment: What your doing is 2x=2B. But not x+B=x+B. Why it still works?

Comment: @user11355 The sum of roots will be constant by Vieta's formula. Alternatively, they are equal to twice the x-coordiante of the vertex of the (symmetric) parabola.